# how to redirect url with .htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect url
1. from `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=product` to `http://www.mysite.com/product.html`
**AND**
2. from `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=product&id=example-example` to `http://www.mysite.com/product/example-example.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: sory, not home but product.html, And how if page=detail than detail.html ??

Comment: how with number 2? check the update my question

Comment: ok check update again.